# CSS Placement on Web Page

Tags: html, css

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|*************** HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH|
|*************** HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH|
|*************** PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP                                    |
|***************                                                                |
|TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT                                                       |
|                                                                               |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sorry for the sketch here. I tried to attach a screen shot, but I couldn't get it to show up. (I'll try to fix it later on another computer if this doesn't explain enough)

**EDIT:** This might help visualize it... http://jsfiddle.net/T3y6E/embedded/result/

I have a `<div>` on a personal web page I am working on. The * represent an image placement. The "H" represent a title placement. The "T" represent a slogan placement. I am trying to move the slogan over so that it is directly below the Title (wanted placement represented by "P")

Here is my HTML for this portion of the page:

```
<div class="logo-image">
      <img src="~/Images/Atlas.png" height="125" width="150" alt="Atlas Logo" />
      <img style="vertical-align:top" src="~/Images/WebPageLogo.png" height="85" width="820" alt="Atlas Logo" />
      <div style="color:#FFF">*A southpaw's approach to bowling*</div>
</div>
```

Here is css that affects it:

```
.logo-image {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: I feel like its a really simple solution that I am just over thinking.

Comment: Pro tip: you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ instead of an image

Comment: Where is your title or slogan? I only see one line of text in your code

Comment: @Huangism: The Title is the second image (WebPageLogo.png). I created it in Paint.NET. Sorry I should have explained that. The title isn't actually text. Its an image of text. :P

Comment: Have you tried floating the first image to the left and leave everthing else as is? http://jsfiddle.net/T3y6E/1/ I just added the styles inline for showing purposes

Comment: adding that little bit fixed it. I thought about trying it but since I had the float in the css, I didn't think it was necessary. I see why though. The float in css effects the div itself and not what is inside that div. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're looking for is `float`. It must be applied to the element you want to be floating, in this case the first image. And the element (with float) must be placed before the element you want it to float from, in your case the title and slogan.

I've created a fiddle with your code to show the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/3xV5Z/1/

Just a reminder: Your slogan is too big. Float won't work well with it if you don't manage your images width.

Comment: This solution puts the elements in the wrong places. It's close, but the placement just isn't right.

Comment: Is the image supposed to be above the text? Like this update: http://jsfiddle.net/3xV5Z/2/

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to LcSalazar's. It uses your css.

```
<div>
    <span class="logo-image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/125" height="125" width="150" alt="Atlas Logo" />
    </span>
    <img style="vertical-align:top" src="http://placekitten.com/820/85" height="85" width="820" alt="Atlas Logo" />
    <div>*A southpaw's approach to bowling*</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't any additional css shown in this example. It looks just like what I already have.

Comment: He rearranged the element's order, instead of changing the css

Comment: oh. I see. you used a <span> instead of a <div>. Well Huangism's comment was the solution that I used that worked. Yours does work as well so I will up-vote it.